# External Table not in expected format open xml

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, openxml, aceoledb

I am trying to upload an excel(.xlsx) file in my application which has been created by the same application via open xml sdk. I am facing the exception 'External table not in expected format'. However if i manually open the file and save it and try again, it is uploaded without any errors.
Is there any way to programatically perform the task of opening the excel file and save ? I cannot ask my user/client to follow this workaround. Any leads would be helpful. Below is the code snippet which is throwing the exception. The line 'con.open()' is throwing the mentioned exception. Please find the connection string used

```
private readonly string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;MAXSCANROWS=0;IMEX=1\";";

public DataTable GetSheetData(string sheetName)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.filePath);
        
        DataTable excelData = new DataTable();
        excelData.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, this.connectionString, this.filePath)))
        {
            con.Open();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "select * from [{0}$]", sheetName), con))
                {

                    dataAdapter.Fill(excelData);
                }
            }
        }

        
        return excelData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround by programatically opening the excel file and saving it by Interop. Now I am able to upload the excel file without any errors.

```
var ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);                

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
```